# Is it possible to detect if content inside a parent element is too wide to fit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm looking at a potential solution to a responsive problem.

Firstly, I'm aware that media queries play a part in this and that I can set breakpoints and even minor breakpoints. This is something that I already do.

However, what I want to do is a little beyond this. I would like to alter the styling on my child html when the overall width would cause the child content to wrap inside its parent, making a more dynamic solution.

Take this example:

```
<nav class="parent" style="width:500">
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li> // uh-ho, this won't fit - wrap it!
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It represents a navigation structure. I would like to stack it when the content becomes too large. The easiest way would be to attach a class to the parent using javascript - this would allow me to stack rather than wrap, and to do it more elegantly than I could achive with just media queries.

The question is how is it possible to detect if the contact is in fact wider than its parent?

Comment: Since you want to use Javascript anyway, just measure the widths?

Comment: Can you not just use JS/JQ to get width of parent and child and compare?

Comment: A little more detail would be great guys - I'm no js expert. Ideally I'd use jquery though.

Comment: Fair point ;) Added a basic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic jQuery solution.

```js
var parent = $('.parent').width();
var child = $('.inline-list').width();

if(child > parent){

  // Adjust accordingly
  // Maybe add/remove/change .inline-list class with $('.inline-list').addClass('.stacked-list').removeClass('.inline-list');

}
```

Comment: Wow, I never realised it would be so simple - thanks for that John.

Comment: All hail JS :) Glad it helped.